# Div Gallery - trying to align div display to "left", and allow responsive height

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to create a blog post display grid. My [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mtsz9tx2/1/) is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mtsz9tx2/1/) These `divs`are currently centered in the middle of the page, which is fine; however, I would like to:

1. Change the alignment of the `divs` to the left, not the center; so that as each post is generated, such is done in the natural reading order.
2. Make the height of the `divs` responsive. By this I mean, the height of the individual `divs` are already responsive; however, the next row of divs is aligned based on the bottom of the single-longest `div` in the row above it. I would like for each `div` to fill in the space not taken by the `div` above it, as depicted in the picture below [image: here]

Currently, my code renders me this: [image: this]
 Any idea as to how I achieve this? Thank you!

Comment: Sure you don't want 'column-count'?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that

Comment: https://w3.org/tr/css3-multicol/#cc

Comment: thanks, it looks complicated, so I'll pass. I have a lot of "markup" if you will, and really don't feel like screwing it up trying to implement a method of coding that I'm unfamiliar with. I do thank you for your time though.

Comment: It's very simple: http://www.webdevout.net/test?01LE&raw

Answer (score 0):

You could use [this](https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/yqrhw) modern CSS approach (won't work for older browsers)

```
 column-break-inside: avoid; // for each content "widget"
```

OR

You can use some of the javascript libraries allowing you to achieve this:

- [bricklayer.js](https://github.com/ademilter/bricklayer)
- [Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)